# Concatenate the square of all the digits of a number

Tags: haskell

Task: given a number (positive or negative), square every digit of it and concatenate them, forming a resulting number.

For example:

9119 should become 811181 = 9^2*10^0 + 1*10^1 + 1*10^2 + 9^2*10^3
(-1) should become (-1)

My code:

```
-- convert a number to the list of digits
-- doesn't work with negative numbers
digs :: Integral x => x -> [x]
digs 0 = [0]
digs x = let
      helper :: Integral x => x -> [x]
      helper 0 = []
      helper n = helper (n `div` 10) ++ [n `mod` 10]
  in
      helper x

squareDigit :: Int -> Int
squareDigit n = let sign = signum n
                    digits = (digs (abs n))
                    digs_sq = map (^ 2) digits
                    -- we can't concat squares as they may have more then 1 digit
                    digs_sq_flat = map digs digs_sq >>= id
                in
                  sign * foldl (\acc x -> x + (acc * 10)) 0 digs_sq_flat
```

Basically, it works:

```
*SquareDigit> squareDigit 9119
811181
*SquareDigit> squareDigit (-9119)
-811181
```

But maybe, my solution can be made more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate out combinators that apply some perspective to your data.

```
squareDigit = overAbs $ overDigits $ concatMap $ digs . (^ 2) where
  overAbs f n = signum n * f (abs n)
  overDigits f = foldl (\acc x -> x + (acc * 10)) 0 . f . digs
```

Answer (score 2):

You could replace

```
digs_sq_flat = map digs digs_sq >>= id
```

with

```
digs_sq_flat = concatMap digs digs_sq
```

`(>>= id)` is the definition of `join` from Control.Monad, which, when specialized to `[a]` is the same thing as `concat`. So you basically have a `map` followed by `concat` which is exactly `concatMap`